# Post multiple checkboxes with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I got an ajax script that posts all my data to a contact-form.php (email)script. Everything works except the checkboxes. It just shows an empty field when I receive the email.

This is the code I got now:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3 style="margin-top:30px;">Type raam</h3>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="Kantel">
            <span>Kantel</span>
        </label>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="Schuif">
            <span>Schuif</span>
        </label>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="Deuropening">
            <span>Deuropening</span>
        </label>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="Draai">
            <span>Draai</span>
        </label>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox5" value="Draai/kantel">
            <span>Draai/kantel</span>
        </label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The mail script:

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Enter your email address
$to = 'email@live.nl';

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Naam',
            'val' => $_POST['name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Email adres',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Adres',
            'val' => $_POST['adres']
        ),
        3 => array(
            'text' => 'Afleveradres',
            'val' => $_POST['afleveradres']
        ),
        4 => array(
            'text' => 'Postcode',
            'val' => $_POST['postcode']
        ),
        5 => array(
            'text' => 'Plaats',
            'val' => $_POST['plaats']
        ),
        6 => array(
            'text' => 'Tweede plaats',
            'val' => $_POST['plaats2']
        ),
        7 => array(
            'text' => 'Telefoonnummer',
            'val' => $_POST['telefoonnr']
        ),
        8 => array(
            'text' => 'Mobiel nummer',
            'val' => $_POST['mobielnr']
        ),
        9 => array(
            'text' => 'Type raam',
            'val' => $_POST['checkbox']
        ),
        10 => array(
            'text' => 'Contactpersoon',
            'val' => $_POST['contactpersoon']
        ),
        11 => array(
            'text' => 'Bericht',
            'val' => $_POST['message']
        )
    );

    $message = "";
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }

    $headers = '';
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    } else{
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResult);

} else {

    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    echo json_encode($arrResult);

}
?>
```

The ajax post:

```
// Ajax Submit
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
        "name": $("#contact-form #name").val(),
        "email": $("#contact-form #email").val(),
        "subject": $("#contact-form #subject").val(),
        "adres": $("#contact-form #adres").val(),
        "afleveradres": $("#contact-form #afleveradres").val(),
        "postcode": $("#contact-form #postcode").val(),
        "contactpersoon": $("#contact-form #contactpersoon").val(),
        "plaats": $("#contact-form #plaats").val(),
        "plaats2": $("#contact-form #plaats2").val(),
        "telefoonnr": $("#contact-form #telefoonnr").val(),
        "mobielnr": $("#contact-form #mobielnr").val(),
        "checkbox": $("#contact-form #checkbox").map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().join(","),
        "message": $("#contact-form #message").val()
    },
```

Now I seperate the results with a comma, but I don't get any result at all in my mail. Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>    "checkbox": $("#contact-form #checkbox").map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().join(","),
> ```

You are getting every element with the id `checkbox` and slapping their values together with commas.

There are just three main problems:

- You aren't allowed more than one element with a given ID
- You actually have zero elements with that ID
- You aren't checking to see if the checkboxes are actually checked or not before including them in the data

It looks like you actually want:

```
$("#contact-form [name='checkbox']:checked")
```

Note, however, that using comma separated data is pretty non-standard.

It would be easier to simply:

```
data: $("#contact-form").serialize()
```

and use PHP "array" style naming conventions for the checkboxes:

```
name="checkbox[]"
```

and then read `$_POST['checkbox']` as an array of values (rather than a comma separated string).

Comment: So I should give all the checkboxes the same ID and then use serialize?

Comment: @twan — No. *You aren't allowed more than one element with a given ID*. If you are using `serialize` then the ids of the form controls don't matter (except for associating a `<label>` with them, which you should do instead of using a `<span>`). Just use `serialize`.

Comment: So the checkbox line would be something like: `"checkbox": $("#contact-form #checkbox").serialize,` ? Do I have to change anything in my mailscript?

Comment: @twan — No. As I said, you would use `data: $("#contact-form").serialize()`. That replaces the entire object you are currently passing to `data`. You need to treat `$_POST['checkbox']` as an array instead of a command separated string.

Comment: One more thing: now it only shows one checked field while I checked multiple. How can I fix that?

Comment: `$_POST['checkbox']` should be an array with the values of all the checked fields

Comment: I already put the results in an array. Like you see in the code I posted: `9 => array(
   'text' => 'Type Raam',
   'val' => $_POST['checkbox']
  ),`  And then in a foreach I read the val, but still it only shows one checked value.

Comment: `$_POST['checkbox']` will be an array of its own. It should contain the values of all that checked checkboxes. That you put it inside another array is beside the point.

Comment: OK, I've gone back and retested this and it turns out that `serialize` doesn't work *quite* the way I thought it does and when it interacts with PHP's really weird form handling, data gets discarded (by PHP). **Change the value of the name attributes of the checkboxes so they end with `[]`**

Comment: Alright, So I also need to put those brackets after the post (for checkbox) inside the mail script, correct?

Comment: @twan — No. Still `$_POST['checkbox']`

Comment: I tried what you said, but now it gives an empty result. I also don't get a success message anymore (still receive the email though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96674/discussion-between-twan-and-quentin).